# Как предовратить смещение?

Tags: вёрстка, css

Всем привет. Есть способ сделать как-то так?

.header и .slider (черная полоска) находятся в #container. У #container прописан padding: 1%, и из-за этого весь контент в нем смещается на 1%.

Как сделать так, чтобы .slider не смещался на 1% (как на картинке)? 
[image]

Comment: Может, где паддинг, добавить
 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: > У #container прописан padding: 1%, и из-за этого весь контент в нем смещается на 1%.

А как должно быть?

По картинке непонятно ничего.

Comment: @Etki нужно сделать так, чтобы .slider не принимал этот padding.

Comment: @misc отступы делаются (margin), а не (padding), при втором весь контент будет вжиматься в родительский блок.